# ASP.NET MVC Actions + Extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, file-extension

I want to have mvc action_name plus file extension in url like `/Home/Index.aspx` instead of `/Home/Index`; which route to Index action of Home Controller. Can anybody help me. Does anybody have any opinion or guideline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "RouteName",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}.aspx",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Can you not do this

Comment: Html.ActionLink can't render links URL like your code. anybody have any specially implemented of extension method like ActionLink to do this correctly?